# How to print data from a structure in a loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

I want a loop that prints the values for each soda.
When I try to print `machine[j].name`, an error is thrown stating that no operator is found or no acceptable conversion exists.

```
struct Soda
{
    string name;
    double price;
    int quantity;
} a, b, c, d, e;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Soda machine[5];
    a.name = "Cola";
    a.price = .80;
    a.quantity = 20;
    b.name = "Root Beer";
    b.price = .75;
    b.quantity = 20;
    c.name = "Lemon-Lime";
    c.price = .90;
    c.quantity = 20;
    d.name = "Grape - Mango";
    d.price = .80;
    d.quantity = 20;
    e.name = "Cream";
    e.price = .80;
    e.quantity = 20;

    cout << setw(5) << "  Name" << setw(15) << " Cost"
        << setw(15) << " Stock" << setw(14) << "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            cout << left << setw(5) << machine[j].name
                 << setw(15) << " Cost" << setw(15) << " Stock"
                 << setw(14);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try printing the values for *one* soda. Then try one soda that is an element in an array. Then try iterating over the array.

Comment: Trying to pring one soda, " cout << a.name ".gives me an error. Looking for alternate method to print it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are mixing up the array with the declaration for separate variables. You have set values on the non-array variables and then you are trying to loop through the array.

Instead, you should set the values on the actual elements of the array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct Soda
{
    string name;
    double price;
    int quantity;
};

int main(){

    Soda machine[5];
    machine[0].name = "Cola";
    machine[0].price = .80;
    machine[0].quantity = 20;
    machine[1].name = "Root Beer";
    machine[1].price = .75;
    machine[1].quantity = 20;
    machine[2].name = "Lemon-Lime";
    machine[2].price = .90;
    machine[2].quantity = 20;
    machine[3].name = "Grape - Mango";
    machine[3].price = .80;
    machine[3].quantity = 20;
    machine[4].name = "Cream";
    machine[4].price = .80;
    machine[4].quantity = 20;


    cout << "Name Cost Stock" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        cout << machine[i].name << " " << machine[i].price << " " << machine[i].quantity << endl; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print out the contents of objects (array of objects ) `machine[i]`, when instead you have assigned values to some different objects: `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`.
 
Solution:
1. Either print `a.name`, `b.name` etc. 
2. or instead of

```
a.name = "Cola";
a.price = .80;
```

write:

```
machine[i].name = "Cola";
machine[i].price = .80;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you marked this as C++, I suggest you try a vector (for machine).

```
int main()
{
    vector<Soda> machine;

    Soda tmpSoda;

    {
       tmpSoda.name = "Cola";
       tmpSoda.price = .80;
       tmpSoda.quantity = 20;
       machine.push_back(tmpSoda);
    }

    {
       tmpSoda.name = "Root Beer";
       tmpSoda.price = .75;
       tmpSoda.quantity = 20;
       machine.push_back(tmpSoda);
    }

    // ....
    {
       tmpSoda.name = "Cream";
       tmpSoda.price = .80;
       tmpSoda.quantity = 20;
       machine.push_back(tmpSoda); 
    }
```

Now all soda's are in the vector (named machine), so you can now report each element in a loop.

```
    cout << "Name Cost Stock" << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<machine.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << machine[i].name << " " 
             << machine[i].price << " " 
             << machine[i].quantity << endl; 
    }
```

---

Since you marked this as C++, I suggest you try a vector of class instances.  Note how the ctor fills in the values of each Soda, and the "show" method uses the private data attributes of each instance.

```
class Soda
{
public:
   Soda(std::string aName,
        double      aPrice,
        int         aQuantity) :
      name(aName),
      price(aPrice),
      quantity(aQuantity)
      {
      }

   ~Soda() {
      name.erase();
      quantity = 0;
   }

   std::string show() {
      std::stringstream ss;
      ss << std::right << std::setw(14) << name  << "   "
         << std::left  << std::setw(8)  << price << " "
         << std::setw(7) << quantity;
      return (ss.str());
   }

   static std::string showHdr() {
      std::stringstream ss;
      ss << std::right << std::setw(14) << "Name"  << "   "
         << std::left  << std::setw(8)  << "Price" << " "
         << std::left  << std::setw(7)  << "Stock";
      return (ss.str());
   }

private:
   std::string name;
   double      price;
   int         quantity;
};
```

Main now reduces to:

```
   std::vector<Soda> machine;

   // load the machine with soda's
   machine.push_back(Soda("Cola", .80, 20));
   machine.push_back(Soda("Root Beer", .75, 20));
   machine.push_back(Soda("Lemon-Lime", .90, 20));
   machine.push_back(Soda("Grape - Mango", .80, 20));
   machine.push_back(Soda("Cream", .80, 20));

   // show machine inventory
   {
      // hdr
      std::cout << Soda::showHdr() << std::endl;

      for (auto i : machine)
         std::cout << i.show() << std::endl;
   }
```